# return Tuple to js in view

Tags: javascript, c#, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Tried using c# 7 Tuples like

```
public (string, bool) ProcessForm([FromBody]Dictionary<string,string> contactFormRequest)
```

But I get the error "CS1031: Type expected". I guess this isn't supported yet.

Then I tried

```
public Tuple<string, bool> ProcessForm([FromBody]Dictionary<string,string> contactFormRequest)
    {
        var message = "test";
        var result = true;
        var tuple = new Tuple<string, bool>(message, result);
        return tuple;
    }
```

This gives no error, but then I cannot pick it up in the view file

```
function handleResult(data) {
    $("#custommessages").html(data.Item1);
}

$2sxc(@Dnn.Module.ModuleID).webApi.post("Form/ProcessForm", {}, newItem, true).then(handleResult);
```

This outputs nothing.

If I return a simple string from the controller, "data" picks it fine.

How do you pick up the values from a Tuple return?

Comment: How about returning a formal type (i.e. a class with 2 properties)? After all, what is a tuple in JS?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a POCO class for serialization:

```
public class SomeResult
{
    public string Message{get;set;}
    public bool Result{get;set;}
}
```

then

```
public SomeResult ProcessForm([FromBody]Dictionary<string,string> contactFormRequest)
{
    var message = "test";
    var result = true;
    return new SomeResult{Message = message, Result = result};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just return a IActionResult?

You can simply write an Anonymous type instead of Tuple!

Named Types may take up some useless spaces (As I thinks that...)

Try This:

```
public IActionResult ProcessForm([FromBody]Dictionary<string,string> contactFormRequest)
{
    var message = "test";
    var result = true;
    //This will create an anonymous type! (you can see its named as "a'")
    var resultData = new { Message = message, Result = result }; 
    return Json(resultData);
}
```

Wish it may help you.

Comment: error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net Core, or just ASP.Net? IActionResult is the class defined in .Net Core, You may try `JsonResult` instead of  `IActionResult` in you code?

Comment: just ASP.Net
It's a CMS (DNN)

Comment: Well then just try change the return type to `IHttpActionResult`, I think this is the base type of result types in ASP.Net